# How to define a Factory in FactoryGirl that uses an http request (get, post, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, http-post, factory-bot, extend

Is there a way to use http requests when defining a factory in FactoryGirl?

Ex.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  Factory :webobject do
    object_handle { 
      post "uri-to-create-object"
      JSON.parse (response.body)[object_handle] 
    }
  end
end

mytestobject = FactoryGirl.build(:webobject)
```

The above results in FactoryGirl doesn't know what post is:

`NoMethodError:
       undefined method`post' for FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner:0x007fd9c6eeb3b0`

I tried adding 'open-uri' and 'net/http' to the Factory file (spec->[factoryfile.rb]). I also tried adding the require lines to the top of the Factory support module (spec->support->model->[factoryfile.rb]). I also tried adding th require lines to the parent file (spec->support->spec_helper.rb) That only seems to support the rspec tests.

Comment: Thank you any/all for help editing the question formatting. Yikes!

Comment: FactoryGirl objects are not meant to contain behaviour and dependencies, such as posting and parsing data. you want to isolate your tests as much as possible from any external dependencies, that's one reason FactoryGirl is used instead of real database object, to isolate the tests from database dependency

Comment: I'm trying to test an API using rspec. The subject of many of the tests is a record generated by the API. I could call the API in the before block of every test to create the record. Then run the tests to verify correct manipulation or record data retrieval. I was just trying to DRY refactor using FactoryGirl, such that the record is produced by factory girl and factory girl holds the reference to the API generated record for every test to use. It may not be possible. Correct Answer goes to one that demonstrates one way or another.